# how to delay the function for 10seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

code for creating csv file with values inside it:

```
function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {
alert(filename);
var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),

 // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
        // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
        tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
        tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

        // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
        colDelim = '","',
        rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

        // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
        csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
            var $row = $(row),
                $cols = $row.find('td');

            return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
                var $col = $(col),
                    text = $col.text();

                return text.replace(/"/g, '""'); // escape double quotes

            }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

        }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
            .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
            .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"',

        // Data URI
        csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);
        alert(csvData);
    $(this)
        .attr({
        'download': filename,
            'href': csvData,
            'target': '_blank'
    });
}
```

The below code is used after clicking button which will export data to csv file.

```
$(".Approve").on('click', function (event) {       
    var that = this; // need to capture `this` context, it doesn't carry into the timer context
 setTimeout(function () {
 exportTableToCSV.apply(that, [ $('#myDiv>table'), 'XYZ.csv'   ]);
 }, 10 * 100);     
  });

});
```

I applied the changes and now Timeout is working but XYZ.csv is not able to download with data.

Answer (score 1):

`exportTableToCSV.apply` already executes the function. You're putting the output of that function in a timer.

Do this instead:

```
var that = this; // need to capture `this` context, it doesn't carry into the timer context
setTimeout(function () {
    var result = exportTableToCSV.apply(that, [ $('#myDiv>table'), 'ExportedBoxResult.csv' ]);
    console.log(result);
}, 10 * 1000);
```

---

```
exportTableToCSV.apply(this[$('#myDiv>table'),'ExportedBoxResult.csv']);
```

There is a syntax error, the brackets don't match up correctly. Did you intend:?

```
exportTableToCSV.apply(this, [ $('#myDiv>table'), 'ExportedBoxResult.csv' ]);
```

Comment: He's missing a comma after `this`

Comment: @MinusFour that would make sense. Moubani can you be a little more descriptive? I can't read minds.

Comment: i have edited the question, timeout is working but i am not able to download the csv file.

Comment: That's outside the scope of this question.